# Pin the two ends together, put a pin here(while pointing at it)

Tags: word-usage

[image: cloth pinned with safety pins along a fold]

So if the two ends are pinned together using a safety pin, can colloquially the following sentence be used to tell someone who's doing it:

> You have to put a safety pin here (while pointing at the position).

Can it be used to mean: pin the two ends together.

Comment: Any particular reason to think not?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make sure;). @James K

Comment: Bear  this in mind: put a pin here and here,for example is fine. **But**: English loves verbs.  So there is also: Pin the folds together here and here. [while pointing]. (I don't think those are ends, they are folds in the material, aren't they?)

Answer (score 1):

"Put a pin here" is correct and easy to understand in context.

Remember that the person that you are speaking to is not a robot. You don't have to make every sentence unambiguous since humans are good at guessing the correct meaning from the situation.

Nobody who is learning to sew is going to think "I will just lay the pin on the surface, since that is the meaning of 'put'."  Certainly the sentence will be understood to mean "put the pin throught the cloth and fasten it."

Comment: How is this about learning to sew? People pin stuff all the time when they are not sewing. We say "put a pin here" or "pin these two x's together"

Comment: Learning to sew is just an example of a situation in which someone might be told to pin a piece of cloth.  For sure, people might be told to "put a pin here" in other contexts and it would be equally clear that it means "pin this together" not "lay a pin on the surface."